# Ionic Cordova iOS run project on device, error: Code Signing Error

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run a simple app with **Ionic version 3.20.0**, **Cordova version 8.0.0** (basically i just created a new project from command line with nothing in it other than the added platforms).

I am getting this error when running with command "ionic cordova run ios --device":

**Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'razvan.secondionicproject' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'razvan.secondionicproject'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'**

When I open and run the project from the platforms/ios project folder with Xcode, it runs fine on my phone. Also when I opened with Xcode I checked automatic signing on, added the correct bundle identifier,  and added myself as the developer.

I have provisioning profiles for development created on the Apple Developer website. When I turn off the automatic signing and choose my provisioning profile that i created from the list (that appears in the Eligibile category) it runs fine in Xcode once more but when i run with 
"ionic cordova run ios" from the project folder i get this new error:

**Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: No profile for team 'Razvan' matching 'IonicPersonalAppDev' found:  Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'Razvan/IonicPersonalAppDev'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
** ARCHIVE FAILED ****

How and where do they want me to drop that provisioning file?

Any help please?

Comment: Oh the joys of ionic/cordova/ios - i feel your pain :-(

Comment: I feel a little better i am not the only one that has/had issues.

Comment: Yea well at least you are starting with the latest version of ionic. Thats good. Us ionic 1 users have been basically left in the dirt. Good luck figuring out your issue brother.

Comment: Thanks @NickyTheWrench I appreciate it.